# Positive Lookbehind Regex

Tags: regex, pcre

Let's say I have the follow String:

```
"TEST="test123; xyz=testtest"|PATH="testCookie=1234;"|COOKIE="testCookie2=4321; testCookie=1234;"
```

I need to write a Regex to only select the `testCookie=1234;` in the `COOKIE=""` Field. I tried it with positive lookbehind `(?<=COOKIE=")` but the problem is my target isn't always on the first position after the `(?<=COOKIE=")`

Can anyone help me with this regex?

Comment: no this would select the first occur for example in the PATH="testCookie=1234; field aswell. I only want to search within the COOKIE="" field

Comment: can you share the full regex you used, the result you got, and your expected result?

Comment: @Lüc If none of the answers works for you, you need to update the question with more details and preferably with more example strings (and what you expect to get out of each one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the value is between the double quotes after `COOKIE="` and you tagged *pcre*:

```
\bCOOKIE="[^"]*\K\btestCookie=[^;"]*;
```

**Explanation**

- `\bCOOKIE="` Match the word `COOKIE` followed by `=`
- `[^"]*` Match optional chars other than `"`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\btestCookie=` Match the word `testCookie` followed by `=`
- `[^;"]*` Match optional chars other than `;` and `"`
- `;` Match literally

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/RQ7CBj/1).

---

To get separate matches after `COOKIE="`

```
(?:\bCOOKIE="|\G(?!^))[^"]*?\KtestCookie\d+=[^"=;]*[;"]
```

**Explanation**

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bCOOKIE="` Match `COOKIE=`
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, not at the start of the string
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `[^"]*?` Optionally match as few as possible chars except `"`
- `\K` Reset the starting point of the reported match (clear the match buffer)
- `testCookie\d+=` Match `testCookie` 1+ digits and `=`
- `[^"=;]*[;"]` Optionally match any char except `"` `=` `;` and then match `;` or `"`

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kyRbZ1/1).

Comment: this looks very good but what if my strings look like this: 

`"TEST="test123; xyz=testtest"|PATH="testCookie=1234;"|COOKIE="testCookie2=4321; testCookie=1234; testCookie3=4321;" `

and i want to select `testCookie` & `testCookie3` in the COOKIE= field?

Comment: `PATH="somepath testCookie4=value4"|FULLREQ="POST /test"|COOKIE="testCookie1=value1; testCookie2=value2; testCookie3=value3; testCookie4=value4; testCookie5=value5"` 

this is a realistic example, i want to select `testCookie4 & testCookie5` in the String above but only in the COOKIE=" field

Comment: @Lüc Like this? https://regex101.com/r/L6unWx/1 Or like this https://regex101.com/r/dAxcPS/1 or like this https://regex101.com/r/HkpdXW/1

Comment: regex101.com/r/dAxcPS/1 this one was the perfect result! Ty very much for your help!

Comment: @Lüc You are welcome, I have added an explanation for that last pattern.

Comment: Amazing solution @Thefourthbird I just learnt about Non capture groups from this

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using PCRE regex, we can try using the `\K` switch here:

```
COOKIE=[^|]*?\KtestCookie=.*?;
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

- `COOKIE=`
- `[^|]*?` match all content without crossing a `|` section boundary
- `\K` reset the match
- `testCookie=.*?;` then match the target `testCookie=` entry

Answer (score 0):

Without lookarounds:

```
COOKIE="[^"]*(testCookie=\d+;)
```

- `COOKIE="` - literal match
- `[^"]*` - anything but `"` zero or more times
- `(` - start of capturing group

  - `testCookie=` - literal match
  - `\d+;` - one or more digits followed by a literal `;`
- `)` - end of capturing group

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RHtcwq/1)

Answer (score 0):

This returns what you want

```
/(?<=COOKIE=".{18}).*(?=")/
```

[Verify here](https://regex101.com/r/l8pUsU/1)

The explanation of the regex:

- `(?<=COOKIE=".{17}\s)`: this lookbehind asserts that your match is preceded by `COOKIE="` and 17 other characters and a space (this is assuming you are sure that the first pair of `key=value` is 17 characters long)
- `.*`: any characters
- `(?=")`: lookahead that asserts your match is followed by a double quote

This way, you get the string between the lookbehind and the lookahead.

**Note:** For the 17 characters guess, it seems lookbehinds **do not support non-fixed lengths**, so having a `.*` would throw an error. That's why I added a fixed length.

Comment: I see...I've updated the answer to better match the question (with a caveat however, due to the limitation of lookbehinds)

Comment: This regex will work for my teststring but I'm looking for a more generic one where I can select my cookies via name (example: testcookie123, testcookie4321) and it should match all of them in the COOKIE field